# Remove quotes around a link

Tags: javascript, json

I have company data for a list of companies and the only way I've been able to click a specific name and produce the data for that specific company was by adding quotes for a line of code `company = '"'+company+'"';`. Without the added quotes, the data doesn't appear for that specific company name being clicked.

I don't like the look of the quotes and I've to use `str_replace()` with no luck. Here's the code:

```
function findCompanies()
{
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      var companies = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
      var list = "<p>There are totally "+companies.totalResults+" companies of which the 10 first are listed here.</p>";
      var nrofcomp = companies.totalResults;

      if (nrofcomp>10){
          nrofcomp = 10;
      }

      for (i=0;i<nrofcomp;i++)
      {
       company = companies.results[i].name;  
       company = '"'+company+'"';        //QUOTE AROUND COMPANY NAME    
       list = list + "<a href='#/' onclick='findCompanyData("+company+");'>"+company+"</a><br/>";
      }
      document.getElementById("ansver").innerHTML = list;
    }
  }
  url ="http://avoindata.prh.fi:80/tr/v1?totalResults=true&maxResults=10&resultsFrom=0&registeredOffice="+document.input.city.value+"&companyRegistrationFrom="+document.input.start.value+"&companyRegistrationTo="+document.input.end.value;
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();      
}
```

Without the quotes around the company name, the links (which display that company's info) doesn't work at all.

Here's how it looks:

[image]

Any advice?

Comment: `onclick='findCompanyData("+company+");'` should be `onclick='findCompanyData(\""+company+"\");'`. Just give the quoting a good thought and it should all make sense.

Comment: Surely you should just make another variable - var quotedCompany = '"'+company+'"' and use the non altered company for display purposes - "<a href='#/' onclick='findCompanyData("+quotedCompany +");'>"+company+"</a><br/>"

Comment: @dmoo What a roundabout way.

Comment: edit. I see whats going on here. @Biffen ftw.

Comment: @dmoo What madness? The quotes make perfect sense.

Comment: @Biffen Thanks for your help. I tried the line of code you suggested, but the links are still present. I'll try playing with it some more.

Comment: @MangoPie with the Biffen line you dont need this line anymore- company = '"'+company+'"';

Comment: @MangoPie If you mean the *quotes* are still present, then you (obviously) should remove the `company = '"'+company+'"';` bit. And take a look at what your code generates.

Comment: Brilliant! It works! Thanks @Biffen I've been trying to figure this out for a while now. Still learning and it was a great lesson. Thanks again!

Comment: @MangoPie Glad to hear it. And I hope you *understand why and how* it works too.

Comment: @Biffen I'm looking at it now and seeing how it works. Is there a name for this method? I'd like to read more on it.

Comment: @MangoPie No name that I know of. ‘*Correct quoting*’, perhaps?